# Using default font styles in Android

Tags: android, text, coding-style, android-layout

How do you use the Android default font sizes in xml?

I tried:

```
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance_Large"
```

But I get:

> error: Error: No resource found that
>   matches the given name (at
>   'textAppearance' with value
>   '@android:style/TextAppearance_Large').

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't it

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

for a TextView?