# finding the correct style in R.attr

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

using:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/...."
```

I would like to style a `TextView` to look like the default style of the "summary" attribute within a `PreferenceScreen`.

using the styles from [this official list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html), I have tried `"summary"` and `"summaryOn"`, but neither of them looks like the default style for summaries. Can anyone explain why, or suggest which one I should be using?

Comment: I think it is `@android:attr`. Not `?android:attr`

Comment: on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405161/using-default-font-styles-in-android it says ?android:attr, but i tried with a @, but nothing changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a theme attribute that refers to the specific semantic of preference summary text, preferences use `?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall` as illustrated here: http://goo.gl/3yZmx (This is the layout file used by the Android framework for preference items.)

Comment: Adam, the link you gave is broken now.  Can you find it in the current source?

Comment: New link for the shortened link above: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4b9a8d75b8796ea07cadd61ceef135c173167c8e/core/res/res/layout/preference.xml The short link in the answer has also been updated.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to reference an ID is using `@`.

Such as `@string/my_string`

Since you wish to reference an ID defined by Android directly, try this:

```
android:textAppearance="@android:id/summary"
```

Comment: still no luck, it just shows large-ish sized text, with a black font.  whereas, it should be (on my phone) a small-ish font, with the colour of light blue

Comment: make sure it's not wrapped in another tag providing a format overriding it. read about style inheritance as well. try `android:textStyle`

Comment: 92Jacko is trying to reference a theme attribute value, not a resource. For what he's trying to do his syntax is correct. `?android:attr/attributeName` will use the value of the current theme's `android:attributeName` item. Think of the ?attr syntax like dereferencing a pointer.

Comment: have a documentation reference for the ?android:attr notation? IntelliJ's Android plugin team may like to know as well.

Comment: Yes: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes